# TYPO3 Flexform + Ckeditor: Empty paragraphs are added on saving

Tags: plugins, ckeditor, typo3, typo3-8.x, flexform

I've got ckeditor attached to a plugins flexforms field. Each time the plugin (ce) is saved, empty paragraphs are added for newlines and `<br>` are converted to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`. No flux or dce in use. TYPO3 is 8.7.13 (and current 9 as well). Just a plugin using `pi_flexform` with a rte field like this:

```
<settings.bookingConfirmationEmailBody>
    <config>
        <type>text</type>
        <rows>5</rows>
        <cols>30</cols>
        <eval>trim,required</eval>
        <enableRichtext>1</enableRichtext>
        <richtextConfiguration>exhibitors_email</richtextConfiguration>
    </config>
</settings.bookingConfirmationEmailBody>
```

I figured out, that on direction "from rte to db", eveything is stored correctly. But "from db to rte", newlines and `<br>` are converted to `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, which multiplies each time i save. Already spent hours on this :(

Comment: Fixed https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60902

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `EXT:flux` if yes, there was a Bug that sounds pretty similar: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1388

Maybe an update or a switch to the flux development branch would fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed soon for 8 LTS and 9 LTS:
https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60902